# Scrolling to the previous div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto

I'm using the scrollTo plugin for jQuery on a website.
I made a vertical scrolling div wher I can scroll to different div by clicking on buttons.
And now I need to make a back button to return to the previous div.

what I want is the opposite of

```
this.next()
```

I tried

```
this.prev()
```

but it doesn't work.

```
$('#tabs').click
(
    function()
    {
        $('#wrapper').scrollTo(this.prev(), 'medium')
    }
);
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#tabs').click
(
    function()
    {
        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).prev(), 'medium')
    }
);
```

In events **this** represents the DOM element, not the jQuery object.

Comment: yes, that's what I did after reading Shog9's answer and it works.
but thanks anyway, and your answer is clearer than his.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a raw element reference - you'll need to wrap it in a jQuery object before you can use jQuery methods like [`prev()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prev): `$(this).prev()`